# Executable Jar and Database

Tags: jar, database-connection, executable

I have made program that requires a database connection (mySQL).
after exporting my system to an executable jar, my jar file does not have any connection with the database.

what are the steps i need to take to solve this predicament please?

Answer (score 0):

what you will need to do is look at the JAR manifest specification which allows you setup classpath entries that your jar will depend on.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Main%20Attributes

Will give you some information.  The Class-Path entry is specifically what you'll be needing to look at.  make references in the MANIFEST.MF that is packaged with your jar to the mysql jar.  I would recommend putting relative to the location of your applications exported jar.

From that you /should/ be able to use java -jar  to execute your program and have the relevant classes for mySQL available for usage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i still cant connect with my database. if it helps i am using eclipse (Galileo) any other solution?

Comment: do you have the mysql jar file (specified in the classpath entry) located in the same directory your executable jar file is? also are you executing the jar (java -jar) in the same directory as both jar files?